# Showing a function is constant

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $f: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ is analytic on $\mathbb{C}$ and that $Im(f(z)) >1$ for all $z$ in $\mathbb{C}$. Show $f$ must be constant.

What I know: $f$ is holomorphic. What connections can I make here. Or can I just use Lioville's theorem (not sure how to apply it). Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Apply a transformation to $f$ so that you can invoke Liouville's theorem on that.

Comment: $|e^{if}|=e^{\Re if}=e^{-\Im f}$ is bounded.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo how did you get the negative?

Comment: @DanielFischer you taught how to do a similar problem. However, I'm having trouble bounding $|e^{if}|$. Where did Andres get a negative from?

Comment: If you write $f = u+iv$, then $if = -v + iu$ and $\operatorname{Re} (if) = -v = - \operatorname{Im} f$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that $f = \Re f + i \Im f$, so that $if = -\Im f + i \Re f$. For us, we know that $\Im f \gg 1$.

Further, when we take the magnitude of a complex exponential, only the real part contributes, i.e. $|e^{x + iy}| = e^x$ (which you should check if you don't know).

This means that if we define a function $g(z) := e^{if}$, which makes sense because $f$ is analytic, then $|g(z)| = |e^{if}| = e^{-\Im f}$. Since $\Im f > 1$, $|g(z)|$ is bounded, and thus by Liouville's theorem, $g$ is constant. Thus $f$ is constant.

Comment: How does the boundedness of $f$ follow from that of $g$? Since you can add to $f(z)$ a random number of $2\pi i$ and still get the same $g$.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is to use Picard's little theorem: Any entire analytic function whose range omits two points must be constant. It is clear that $0,1 \not\in f(\mathbb{C})$, so $f$ is constant.